# how do i subtract from a form request and update laravel db

Tags: php, laravel

i want a form to substract from the amount in accounts table

help me out. here is my code

```
public function transferSend(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'rec_acc_name' => 'required',
            'swift_code' => 'required',
            'rou_no' => 'required',
            'rec_bank_add' => 'required',
            'trans_amou' => 'required',
            'remarks' => 'required',
            
        ]); 
         $balance = DB::table('accounts')->pluck('amount');
    if($request->trans_amoun < $balance) 
    {
        return ('you don no have enough balance');
    } else{
$request->trans_amoun = $trans_amoun
  $newbalance = $trans_amoun
        $newbalance = DB::table('accounts')
        ->update('amount');
    }
```

i'm new to php and laravel please help

Answer (score 1):

PHP code requires ; at the end of every statement. You can't leave them out. This isn't javascript.

Updating the request has no effect. This code does nothing.

```
$request->trans_amoun = $trans_amoun;
```

You have no `WHERE` clause so your query is getting all the rows in the table. You then proceed to use the returned data as if it is a single value.

Let;s say the `accounts` table had a column named `id`, you would do something like this:

```
$balance = DB::table('accounts')
    ->where('id', $request->id)
    ->value('amount');
```

The above code will return a single value.

Read this:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table

You state you are trying to subtract an amount so you need to take the amount from the database and subtract the amount in the request.

```
$newbalance = $balance - $request->trans_amount;
```

The update code is broken. It also needs to know which row to update. You also have to give it the columns you want to update and the new values for those columns.

```
DB::table('accounts')
    ->where('id', $request->id)
    ->update(['amount' => $newbalance]);
```

Read this:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#update-statements

I really recommend that you spend some time reading the laravel docs.